# Precision lost calling cv2.cartToPolar with angleInDegrees set to False

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am using `opencv 4.0.0` in python.

When calling the function `cv2.cartToPolar` with `x` value to -12 and `y` value to 0, with parameter `angleInDegrees` set to False, I'm getting a wrong answer. It should be `pi` instead I get `3.14159274`, which is greater than `pi`.

```
x = np.asarray([[-12]], dtype = "float64")
y = np.asarray([[0]], dtype = "float64")

mag, angle = cv2.cartToPolar(x, y, angleInDegrees=True)
print('mag', mag)
print('angle', angle)

>>> mag [[12.]]
>>> angle [[180.]]

x = np.asarray([[-12]], dtype = "float64")
y = np.asarray([[0]], dtype = "float64")

mag, angle = cv2.cartToPolar(x, y, angleInDegrees=False)
print('mag', mag)
print('angle', angle)

>>> mag [[12.]]
>>> angle [[3.14159274]]
```

I expect the output of `3.14159265`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting observation. This must have to do with the precision of floating point arithmetic as pointed out by @Sushi. As per the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#carttopolar), the output of `cv2.cartToPolar` function is given by

[image]

```
x = np.asarray([[-12]], dtype = "float32")
y = np.asarray([[0]], dtype = "float32")

print(cv2.cartToPolar(x, y, angleInDegrees=False)[1])
print(np.radians(np.arctan2(y, x) * 180 / np.pi))

x = np.asarray([[-12]], dtype = "float64")
y = np.asarray([[0]], dtype = "float64")

print(cv2.cartToPolar(x, y, angleInDegrees=False)[1])
print(np.radians(np.arctan2(y, x) * 180 / np.pi))
```

output:

```
[[3.1415927]]
[[3.1415927]]
[[3.14159274]]
[[3.14159265]]  # check this result
```

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gac5f92f48ec32cacf5275969c33ee837d): "The angles are calculated with accuracy about 0.3 degrees". So this is expected behavior. Also your value differs from PI on the 7th decimal place so that may be caused by the precision of floating point arithmetic.